# How the database tables structure should be to map State and Cities in sql phpmyadmin?

Tags: database, database-design

I am very new to database and server side API's, so I have to clarify the below one with you guys.
I am designing a feature like there will be a set of states and each state have the set of cities.

I should map the group of cities to a particular state like the below example,

Ex:

- Tamilnadu

  ```
   Chennai

   Coimbatore

   Vellore

   Salem

   Tiruppur

   Erode
  ```
- Andhra Pradesh

  ```
   Chittoor

   Kadapa

   Karnool

   Ananthapuram

   Nellore
  ```

For this feature how the database tables structure should be look like.

Can anyone clear me about this, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple database with only two tables :

First, "States" table where you have the name of the state and an unique id (primary key) :

```
  id:1, state:"Tamilnadu"
  id:2, state:"Andhra Pradesh"
```

> ==> id(int), state(varchar)

Second, "Cities" table with the name of the city, unique id of the city (primary key) and a reference to the "States" table (foreign key)

```
  id:1, city:"Chennai", stateId:1
  id:2, city:"Chittoor", stateId:2
```

> ==> id(int), city(varchar), stateId(int)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

State Table Schema:

```
id, statename
```

City Table Schema:

```
id, stateid, cityname
```

Put cities with the corresponding state id in it. 
To fetch them, get the state list and cities as per state list by using stateid column

Answer (score 0):

You should have at least two tables one form States and one for cities. 
Than you can store State ID in city table to identify what state that city belongs to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: those `place` parent_id=0 that mean state. those parent_id->parent_id=0 those are sub_city.

```
+------+----------------+----------------+--------+
| id   | place_name     |   parent_id    | status |
+------+----------------+----------------+--------+
|  1   | Tamilnadu      |        0       | active |
|  2   | Chennai        |        1       | active |
|  3   | Coimbatore     |        1       | active |
|  4   |subCityOfChennai|        2       | active |
|  5   | Andhra Pradesh |        0       | active |
|  6   | Chittoor       |        5       | active |
|  7   | Kadapa         |        5       | active |
|  8   | Karnool        |        5       | active |
|  9   |subCityOf Kadapa|        7       | active |
+------+----------------+----------------+--------+
```

> Here you can use subcity feature that mean unlimited subcity facility.
>   I have added `subCityOfChennai` `id=4` and `subCityOf Kadapa` id=9.